# Checkbox background size in JavaFx-Css

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am styling a checkbox inside a menu button, and i am trying to change the color of the box's background but it appears the size of it (red) is larger than the margin (yellow), how can I change the size or what would be the attribute to change? I tried changing the `size` attribute in CSS but it is not working.

```
.menu-item .check-box > .box {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-border-color: yellow;
}
```

[Example Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57gmf.png)

Comment: Hi SergioM, have you checked the [JavaFX CSS reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)?

Comment: Hi Travis, 
Yes I have gone through it without any luck.